# Web Application and WCF service deployment on Windows Azure

Tags: sql, wpf, wcf, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an existing Application that has the following parts
1- Customer Web Application
2- Customer Web Service
3- Admin WPF Application
4- Admin Web Service

My task is to convert the Application and Services to Azure Platform and deploy them. I have the following questions and i will be be thankful if anybody helps me

1- The Web Application is using Memberhsip Providers. What to do with the ASPNETDB.MDF?

2- The Web Application is using Session. Can i directly move the application to Azure or do i need to do something first ?

3- The Web Services donot have a *.asmx file and are using Service Host. How to deploy them on Azure ?

4- Since i have 2 Webservices, and i will have to deploy them seperately. Can i deploy 2 Webservies and 1 Web Application in a single Azure hosting ?
5- Can i deploy the WPF Application ?

Note: The database for all of these application is the same and will be deployed on Sql Azure.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

To answer question 1 and 2 I suggest you take a look at the [Azure Providers](http://azureproviders.codeplex.com/), these allow you to use a MembershipProvider and Session in Windows Azure using Table and/or Blob Storage. Besides that there are other implementations that leverage [SQL Azure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191/en-us) (MembershipProvider) and [AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic3.aspx) (Session).

Then for question number 3 it shouldn't be an issue to deploy web services using a Service Host. In fact, when you deploy a Web Role to Windows Azure, this simply runs in IIS on a Windows Server 2008 (R2) instance, and this works fine with a Service Host (I assume you mean [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx)).

Your 4th question is about deploying multiple web services. This depends on your needs and on your budget. One option is to deploy the web application and the 2 web services separately, each on one Web Role. To get the SLA this means you would need 6 instances, but you'll be able to scale each component independently. On the other hand, you could also combine all your applications in a single web role (your initial cost will be lower). This can be done by using multiple virtual applications applications in a single web role (and if you want you can combine this with host headers): http://blog.structuretoobig.com/post/2012/01/17/One-Azure-Web-Role-Multiple-Websites.aspx

For your last question about deploying a WPF application, well it depends. There are a few things you need to take into account. If your WPF application connects to your SQL Azure database it would be best if you access it from a fixed IP, since you'll need to [modify the SQL Azure firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx) to allow external connections and this is based on IP (or an IP range).

It's also important to note that the WPF application is a client side application and it can't run in Windows Azure (you could through remote desktop, but that's not a real solution imo). Anyways, you could still 'trick' the user into thinking it runs in the cloud or at least make it accessible through your Web Role:

- You could deploy it as a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) application in your Web Role
- You could convert it to an [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) application and host it in your Web Role, this way the user will never leave the browser and it will look like as if the application is hosted online.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have deployed all the webservices and the applications as separate web roles(this project is my assignment, so meeting the SLA is not a requirement). As far as the Azure Providers you mentioned, i have used this http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers and it integrates and works beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: I was a little confused because i found no *.asmx file. but after searching a little bit on the internet i figured it out that i can make a new service and add all the code in the new service. I had no issue with deployment. In future, i will definetly consider your answer for the deployment of WCF services.